# How to use nested for loops?

Tags: java

This is my code

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    int tri,  a;
    int b;

    System.out.println("Enter the size you want your triangle to be:");

    tri = keyboard.nextInt();      

    for (a = 1; a <= tri; a++)
    {
        for (b = 1; b <= a; b++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

    }
}
```

When i run and enter ex. 3 i want the code to say

> [image]

I know i might be missing some loops as I am in the beginning stages of the code only. I am running to see if everything goes as i want and it isn't. When i enter 3 i get everything on one line:

`******`

Help with explanation would be appreciated.
It should work with any number not just 3

Comment: This was asked before. This can be done by a recursive method.

Comment: You need to tell the computer when it should go to the next line by using `System.out.println();` somewhere in your code.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Sure it *can* be. However, the question is about doing it with nested for loops.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I can't find anything related to recursion in this question, looks pretty specific: use nested loops.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make two changes to your code. First, you need to end the line on each iteration of the outer loop. Second, you need to do the bottom part of the triangle. Here's code that does it both:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    int tri,  a;
    int b;

    System.out.println("Enter the size you want your triangle to be:");

    tri = keyboard.nextInt();      

    for (a = 1; a <= tri; a++)
    {
        for (b = 1; b <= a; b++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        // this next call ends the current line
        System.out.println();
    }
    // now for the bottom of the triangle:
    for (a = tri - 1; a >= 1; a--) {
        for (b = 1; b <= a; b++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives the whole solution to OP's problem so is indeed a solution. I though that this was an exercise and OP had a problem using `System.out.print` and `System.out.println` and then leave OP to keep dealing with this new t̶o̶y̶  method.

Comment: thanks but what exactly does thi do System.out.println();
i mean how does the program know to put 1* on first line and 2* on the second and so forth. I am just havinf trouble understanding and the thought process behind this.

Comment: @xpression - It starts a new line. (Think of it as printing a blank line, except there may already be stuff on the line from previous calls to `System.out.print()`.)

Comment: `System.out.println()` (aka sopl) is very similar to `System.out.print()`, but it adds a new line at the end of the output. It's very similar to typing `System.out.print(myString + '\n');`

Comment: that last for loop, why is it that b=1 and b++. Shouldn't it be b--

Comment: For the last loop why is b=1 shouldn't b=a so if tri=5 a will =5-1 and b=a which is b=4 and print 4*. And why if b++ shouldn't it be --. I know your code works but I am trying to understand it so in future when i have to it by myself.

Comment: @xpression - In the last loop, you need to print out `a` copies of "*" at each iteration of the outer loop. In the inner loop, `b` is just used to count up to `a`, generating one "*" at each iteration; The actual value of `b` is not for anything inside the loop body.

Answer (score 1):

Or just one loop:

```
int x = 3; // input tri
var y = x*2;

for (int i = 0; i < y; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < (i < x ? i : y-i); ++j) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be done every time the outer loop is accessed:

```
system.out.println();
```

this allows the *'s to be on different lines, also this code only does the top half of the triangle. In order to do the bottom half, you have to count down from tri.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.print` prints everything in the current output buffer i.e. the console. You must use `System.out.println` (note the `ln` suffix) to print something and a break line.